# How do I solve MissingOsLoader error on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

I recently ran a Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 live CD on a windows
machine. I thought that this was perfectly safe but it damaged the boot loader of the Windows installation and now I can
not get Windows to boot properly. The Disc Repair tool (GUI) concludes
'MissingOsLoader'.

I have tried all the 

  `bootrec /fixmbr`

etc and I downloaded and ran "WindowsRepair" from SourceForge -- no luck.

The most important thing here is, of course, not to destroy the
contents of the hard drive, but I also think that there must be a way
to restore the Windows installation already present on the hard
drive.

Now I have a brand new Windows 7 DVD and I have seen suggestions that
I could start the computer with this DVD and click my way through
until I see a link to "Repair Windows" (or similar).

Can I use this option without facing the risk of loosing the contents
of the older Windows installation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning your hard drive? If not you can put the new Windows 7 disk in, then as soon as it comes up hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> for the CMD window.

Type:

```
Diskpart
List Disk
List Vol
List Part
Select Disk 0
Clean All
```

When this is finished, type:

```
Create Partition Primary Size=4700
Create Partition Primary
```

When that is finished, type:

```
Exit
Exit
```

The CMD window will close.
Your windows install window should still be up.
Run the install.

Comment: What does this do? It seems like running the install would "overwrite everything". I want to do the opposite and (ideally) reset the old Windows installation to it's working state.